# encryption of email in GitHub Archive

Tags: github, encryption, github-archive

I queried GitHub archive and got the mail encrypted.

The mail that I got in the query - `9b2aaf20c3f2c0c9b21ada60e9bca6ef34b3dbc7@outlook.com`

The mail it suppose to be - `phil12328@outlook.com`

Anyone knows how to decrypt it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is `sha1` hash and not an encryption.

`sha1("phil12328")` -> `"9b2aaf20c3f2c0c9b21ada60e9bca6ef34b3dbc7"`

Since hashes are one-way functions, there's no easy way going backward to the original input. However, there are online tools doing reverse lookup like http://reverse-hash-lookup.online-domain-tools.com/ where you give them hash and if they have a match you get a potential matching input